# How can I add to select multiple values of subquery in main query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Query :

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `ID`
IN GROUP_CONCAT(
(
SELECT post_id
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE `meta_key` = 'friday_happy_hour_start_time'
AND `meta_value` <= '9'
) && (
SELECT post_id
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE `meta_key` = 'friday_happy_hour_end_time'
AND `meta_value` >= '9'
)
)
```

Subquery 1 and 2 having multiple result, so I have used GROUP_CONCAT(). but it is not working.
I want all the posts where 9 is equal or between `meta_value`('s) of `meta_key` = 'friday_happy_hour_end_time' and `meta_key` = 'friday_happy_hour_start_time'.Please provide me solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `group_concat` and multiple sub queries this can be easily done by joining `wp_postmeta` twice with posts and defined your criteria

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM `wp_posts` p
JOIN wp_postmeta m ON(p.ID = m.post_id)
JOIN wp_postmeta m1 ON(p.ID = m1.post_id)
WHERE m.`meta_key` = 'friday_happy_hour_start_time' 
AND m1.`meta_key` = 'friday_happy_hour_end_time' 
AND m.`meta_value` <= '9' 
AND m1.`meta_value` >= '9'
```

Comment: Thanks You. And How the query will be, while using $meta_query[] ? Is this correct? $meta_query[] = array(
   array(   
   'key'     => 'sunday_happy_hour_start_time',   
   'value'   => '9.5',   
   'type'    => 'DECIMAL(4,2)',    
   'compare' =>  '>=' 
   ),
   array(   
   'key'     => 'sunday_happy_hour_end_time',   
   'value'   => '9.5',   
   'type'    => 'DECIMAL(4,2)',      
   'compare' =>  '<=' 
   )
  );

Comment: @testcromosys you can  use `wpdb` class for raw queries an for multiple meta_keys i can't tell you how use wp's functions but there is a reference here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40322/query-multiple-meta-key-values

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using group_contact you could achieve what you want in a single sub query as such.
The brackets are the important factor here.

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `ID`
IN (
SELECT post_id
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE 
(`meta_key` = 'friday_happy_hour_start_time' AND `meta_value` <= '9')  
OR 
(`meta_key` = 'friday_happy_hour_end_time' AND `meta_value` >= '9')

)-- End of IN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `ID` IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT post_id
    FROM `wp_postmeta`
    WHERE `meta_key` = 'friday_happy_hour_start_time'
    AND `meta_value` <= '9'

    UNION DISTINCT 

    SELECT DISTINCT post_id
    FROM `wp_postmeta`
    WHERE `meta_key` = 'friday_happy_hour_end_time'
    AND `meta_value` >= '9'
)
```